# Get GCM registration id of already registered device

Tags: android, push-notification, session-cookies, google-cloud-messaging

I am using GCM with my application. It is working fine. I am storing it in database also.
 But now as per my requirement, I want GCM registration id of already registered device at later time. So Is there any way to get this ? I don't want to store it in `Cookies` or in `Session`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, implementing your remote server (as this infrastructure requires) in your favorite language and storing it somewhere: your MySQL database, a file, or whatever you want.

Resuming, you need to implement a web-service that will store any registered GCM ids somewhere (for instance, a local MySQL database), so it can later retrieve it. Doing it this way, you also need to care about timeouts (for instance, if a client doesn't send a keepalive within X time, just delete it from the database).

Comment: sorry to say, but this is not my solution. Is there any way by which I get same id again from GCM ?

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but this is the way it works. And yes, you can get the same ID again using the same device. Usually Google will grant the same ID for the same device for an undefined amount of time (which might be days, weeks or months).

Comment: `String regid = gcm.register("YOUR-SENDER-ID");`. This will return you the GCM id.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `gcm.register` multiple times (without calling `gcm.unregister`) will return the same registration ID. However, there is no reason to do that - it causes an unnecessary communication of your app with the GCM server.

You can store the registration ID in the app's shared preferences, as is shown in the [official GCM demo app](http://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/GcmClient/src/main/java/com/google/android/gcm/demo/app/DemoActivity.java) :

```
/**
 * Stores the registration ID and the app versionCode in the application's
 * {@code SharedPreferences}.
 *
 * @param context application's context.
 * @param regId registration ID
 */
private void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regId) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = getGcmPreferences(context);
    int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
    Log.i(TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, regId);
    editor.putInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, appVersion);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Whenever you need it in your app, you get it from the shared preferences (unless a new version of your app is installed, in which case Google recommend to invalidate the stored registration ID and call `gcm.register` again) :

```
/**
 * Gets the current registration ID for application on GCM service, if there is one.
 * <p>
 * If result is empty, the app needs to register.
 *
 * @return registration ID, or empty string if there is no existing
 *         registration ID.
 */
private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = getGcmPreferences(context);
    String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
    if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
        return "";
    }
    // Check if app was updated; if so, it must clear the registration ID
    // since the existing regID is not guaranteed to work with the new
    // app version.
    int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
    if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
        Log.i(TAG, "App version changed.");
        return "";
    }
    return registrationId;
}
```